# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+\sin(n)}$ absolutely convergent, convergent, or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> Is this series absolutely convergent, convergent, or divergent?$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+\sin(n)}$$

How would we show this is convergent? Alternating test? Limit comparison test?

First I did $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2n+\sin(n)}$$ which is equal to zero and $b_{n+1} < b_{n}$. SO we know it is convergent.

Next to test absolute convergence, I did limit comparison test.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+\sin(n)}\bigg| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+\sin(n)}\text{ .}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/(2n+\sin(n))}{1/n} = 1/2$$

which is greater than zero and since $1/n$ diverges, then so does
$1/(2n+\sin(n))$. Therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+\sin(n)}$$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset mathematics. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: An edit is in the review queue.

Comment: Thank you for the edit

Comment: Why $b_{n+1} < b_n$?  xpaul explains in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ a_n=\frac{1}{2n+\sin(n)}. $$
Clearly $a_n>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Since
$$ 2(n+1)+\sin(n+1)-(2n+\sin(n))=2+(\sin(n+1)-\sin(n))\ge0, $$
one has
$$ 2(n+1)+\sin(n+1)\ge2n+\sin(n)$$
or
$$ a_{n+1}=\frac1{2(n+1)+\sin(n+1)}\le\frac1{2n+\sin(n)}=a_n.$$
So $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing. By the AST, $\sum_{n=1}(-1)^na_n$ converges. Since
$$ a_n=\frac{1}{2n+\sin(n)} \sim\frac{1}{2n} $$
and $\sum\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges, one concludes $\sum_{n=1}(-1)^na_n$ converges conditionally.

Comment: To test for absolute convergence or conditional convergence, what would we do? Ratio and Root tests don't work in this case.

Comment: It is better to use ratio comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

For large $n$, the term $\sin n$ becomes neglectable and you end-up with an alternating Harmonic series. (Or you can squeeze with

$$\frac1{2(n+1)}<\frac1{2n+\sin n}<\frac1{2(n-1)}.)$$

The Harmonic series is known to be convergent but not absolutely.